# In ga('create' 'ua-' 'auto'), what does 'auto' stand for?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics.js

As per the doc , '`auto`' in `ga('create' 'ua-' 'auto')` is described as below.

opt_configObject – An optional object containing configuration field/value pairs.

But, I am not sure, I completely get this.

What is the difference between `ga('create' 'ua-' 'auto')` and say I give `ga('create' 'ua-' 'mysite.com')` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree the method signature and the myriad of valid combination can make it confusing.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
```

is the same as

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', {
  cookieDomain: 'auto'
});
```

More info on using 'auto' for cookieDomain can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains#auto

To answer your questions, there's no difference between specifying `'auto'` and `'mysite.com'` if your site's domain name is 'mysite.com', but there would be a difference if your site were hosted at 'subdomain.mysite.com'.

Comment: Thanks Philip. What difference it makes when I have subdomain? Even if the site is hosted as subdomain.mysite.com, I would want it to write to mysite.com

Comment: The `'auto'` value automatically writes to the highest level domain it can. So if you use `'auto'` on subdomain.mysite.com it will set the cookie on mysite.com.

Comment: Could you add a part in your answer to what happens when you don't specify this optional field? The default value is "document.location.hostname (normalized)" according to the docs. It's unclear if this is the same as 'auto'. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#cookieDomain

Comment: I created an issue for the documentation too to improve this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132274781

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue awhile back where a client had all of his domains say: 
ga('create' 'ua-' 'mysite.com')
That's basically an old method of specifying the cookie to a domain. Might as well change when google changes correct?
I changed them to 'auto' because it simplifies subdomain tracking. 
See the official youtube video.
[Google YouTube Video](https://youtu.be/nmfUoSyFBSk)